# Rebar lap splice tail bend

Tags: concrete, reinforcement

Is it a thing to bend the tails of rebars in lap splice?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lap Splices:

[image]

Lap Splice (left), Splice by Mechanical Coupler (right):

[image]

You need to check the governing structural code of your local for rules and requirements.